# sql: query to find max count with extra columns as well

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

**Input table:events**

```
month      user
2020-11   user_1
2020-11   user_5
2020-11   user_3
2020-12   user_2
2020-10   user_4
2020-09   user_6
```

**GOAL**

1. I want `max(distinct user)` grouped by `month` column.
2. my final result need two columns one is `month` and another one is `max_count`

I need output similar to this

```
month    max_count
2020-11    3
```

I followed some approach

Approach1:

```
select max(cnt) max_count
from
(
select month,
       count(distinct user) as cnt
       
from events

group by 1
)
```

**if i follow this approach, it is just giving me only `max_count` but i need month column as well**

I know we can use something like `order by`  and `limit` to get the result. But i dont want that hacky way.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I am running these queries in amazon athena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select month, cnt
from
(
  select month,
         count(distinct "user") as cnt,  
         dense_rank() over (order by count(distinct "user") desc) as rnk
  from events
  group by month
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

---

`user` is a reserved keyword in SQL and should be quoted (or better: find a different name)

Comment: thanks, i got it. Is there any other approach  to achieve the result

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `order by` and some clause to limit the results:

```
select month, count(distinct user)
from events
group by month
order by count(distinct user) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that not all databases support the standard `fetch` clause.  You might want `limit` or `select top (1)` or something similar.

Comment: yes, I can use this approach but it is a kind of hacky way. I want something robust

Comment: @siva . . . What do you think is "hacky" about this?  I don't know what you might mean by "robust" but this is a concise SQL query to do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: what i mean is, I dont want to use `limit`. Is there any way like using sub-queries etc.

Comment: @siva . . . Subqueries are more expensive, unless you have a particular reason.

Comment: got it. Thanks @gordon Linoff